# Spring Security + REST + postgreSQL

Tags: spring, security, spring-security

I did a tutorial https://auth0.com/blog/securing-spring-boot-with-jwts/ about authorization using Spring Security, but this example use hardcoded user data. I would like to authorize using database PostgreSQL. How can I do that? Or do you know some examples on github using Spring REST Security and PostgreSQL?

```
package com.example.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        // We filter the api/login requests
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
        .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Create a default account
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("admin")
        .password("password")
        .roles("ADMIN");
  }
}
```

Comment: you should create your own userdetailservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it with your custom userdetailservice like this:

```
@Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailService userDetailsService;

@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                ;
    }
```

and add customuserdetail service :

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {


    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = getUserFromDatabase();

        UserItem userItem =  new UserItem(user.getUsername(),user.getPassword(),true,true,true,true, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());;

        userItem.setAuthorities(AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_USER"));
        return userItem;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a bean for dataSource like this

```
@Bean
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
     DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
     driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
     driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb");
     driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("postgres");
     driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("root");
     return driverManagerDataSource;
 }
```

And then autowire `javax.sql.DataSource` inside your WebSecurityConfig class:

```
 @Autowired
 DataSource dataSource;
```

if your password is Bcrypt encoded then create a bean for passwordEncoder

```
    @Bean(name="passwordEncoder")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordencoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Configure authentication like this:

```
 public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
  .usersByUsernameQuery(
   "select email,password from users where email=?").passwordEncoder(passwordencoder());
 }
```

and finally hit the `/login` route.